# Unable to access website via Route 53 domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, traffic

I have multiple EC2 instances connected to a load balancer and the traffic is routed to load balancer using Route53.

Suddenly, I can longer access my website if I type my domain name "www.domain.com". I tried to debug the problem by directly typing the load balancer DNS in the browser and it worked.

To investigate the problem further, I created a single instance and directed the traffic using route53 to the current public IP of the instance. If I use the domain name "www.domain.com" in the browser, I get an error stating that the site can't be reached. If I use the public IP of the instance I can reach the page. I think that means that Route 53 is not directing the traffic to instance.

How can I check that because I have been in this problem for almost two days. Is there is a way to check whether Route 53 routes traffic or not? I am sure my security group of allows traffic For HTTP, HTTPS, SSH and the port numbers are correct.

Comment: Does Route 53 show health check issues? Does DNS resolve your domain name correctly?

Comment: @jarmod sorry how can I check that DNS resolve domain name correctly in route53

Comment: @jarmod I checked the test record set and DNS response CODE is NOERROR

Comment: You can use online tools to resolve DNS hostnames to IP addresses or you can use utilities such as dig. If you can hit the website via the LB IP and via the LB name but you can't hit the website using the R53 domain name then I'd suspect your R53 config or R53 health checks.

Comment: It it a 504 error or a browser error? also what happens when you change your hosts file to point the domain to an IP address of the load balancer and try and visit it? Are you using an ALIAS record because I seem to remember them not using health checks and what load balancer are you using? If you really want you can enable DNS logging

Comment: @jarmod sorry for the late reply. I used dig and everything seems to be working properly but I still cant access any other tools that I can use to debug that issue

Comment: @SamCollins I am totally directed to a different. I am using an Alias in my records for the load balancer.I am using an Application load balancer. I tried switching on and off the health check but nothing works